# JSDoc Types for Runtime Validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, jsdoc, type-safety

We are currently considering adding JSDoc with typing / type safety to our projects. We favor JSDoc with types over Typescript because we write mostly self-contained functions and don't want the overhead of Typscript in the toolchain. We also have REST endpoints with incoming parameters. We want to validate these as well - using ajv for example, but we don't want to write the types twice (in the validator and in JSDoc). What is the best possible option to avoid repeating ourselves? We know that JSDoc are only comments and it is difficult to interpret anything.

- NestJS has an interesting approach, but also uses TypeScript (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)
- One idea was to have it automatically generated (without an idea of how to do that in a practical way) and still have it in two places. But then it would still have to be changed in two places.